# How to calculate Confidence Interval of a Distribution with Data concentrated in subintervals

Tags: python, probability

How would I calculate the 95% confidence interval of a list whose distribution looks like this?
[Distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGhTk.png)
When I use various python libraries to do so, the confidence interval returned is unreasonably small.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have what appears to be a log normal type of distribution

i would do something like this:

```py
from scipy.stats import lognorm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)

# Calculate the first four moments:
s = 0.9 # 0.954
mean, var, skew, kurt = lognorm.stats(s, moments='mvsk')

# Display the probability density function (pdf):
x = np.linspace(lognorm.ppf(0.01, s),
                lognorm.ppf(0.99, s), 100)
ax.plot(x, lognorm.pdf(x, s),
       'r-', lw=5, alpha=0.6, label='lognorm pdf')

# Check accuracy of cdf and ppf:
vals = lognorm.ppf([0.001, 0.5, 0.999], s)
np.allclose([0.001, 0.5, 0.999], lognorm.cdf(vals, s))
True


# And compare the histogram:
ax.legend(loc='best', frameon=False)
plt.show()

# get the confidence
y = lognorm.interval(0.95, s, loc=0, scale=1)
print(y)
```

[image]

result

```
(0.1713636133687539, 5.835544549636219)
```